# Shadow to a label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I need to add shadow to all side to a label.It will look like this.

[image]
How Can I do this?Please help.I am using shadowOffset ,but it is not giving shadow in all side.Please help.

Comment: That's not a shadow, it's an outline.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the white outline around the letters?

Comment: @ rob may off yes I am asking about white outline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're asking how to add the white outline, you can't do that with a plain `UILabel`.  You need to draw the text using Core Graphics (aka Quartz 2D).  Something like this:

```
CGContextRef gc = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(gc); {
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(gc, kCGTextFillStroke);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(gc, UIColor.blueColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(gc, UIColor.whiteColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(gc, kCGLineJoinRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(gc, 2);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(gc, CGSizeMake(-1, 2), 2, UIColor.blackColor.CGColor);
    [@"Card" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 20) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]];
} CGContextRestoreGState(gc);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a project by [nicklockwood on gitHub](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXLabel). It improves upon the standard UILabel by providing a subclass that supports soft shadows, inner shadow and gradient fill, and which can easily be used in place of any standard UILabel.Have a look at it.It will be useful to you.